# Prove this sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is not any exercise on itself, but I was reading a proof in which a sequence similar to this appeared:

$$a_n=n\lambda^{n-1}, \quad|\lambda|<1$$

In essence. Then I came across the assertion, without any further explanation, that $(a_n)_n\leq M$ for some $M>0$.

How is this though? Because clearly $n\rightarrow\infty$ while $\lambda^{n-1}\rightarrow0$, how to break this indetermination?

Comment: The short answer is you have polynomial growth time exponential decay,  and exponential is bigger than polynomial.  Leaving it as a comment for someone to formalize it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove that if $u\in\Bbb R$ and $a\in(0,1),$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^ua^n=0$ ([Here is a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238513/proof-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracn-alpha1pn-0-from-rudins-pr)). Thus, your sequence in bounded.

Comment: Oh alright, thanks man ;)